# i am able to hide 1st texbox's keyboard but not for the 2nd textbox in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7

Hi i am trying to hide the keyboard when it appears while typing. I have successfully done the code for the 1st textbox which is username_textbox, but when i do the same code for 2nd textbox which is password_textbox keyboard does not hide.

Can anyone help me out in this how to hide keyboards when there are multiple textboxes.

MY code is:

**ViewController.h**

```
//@interface ViewController : UIViewController
//
//@end


@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameTextbox;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordTextbox;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [[self navigationController]setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES ];

    [self.usernameTextbox setDelegate:self];
    [self.passwordTextbox setDelegate:self];

}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.usernameTextbox resignFirstResponder];
       return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textField2ShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.passwordTextbox resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Not important to your issue but why are your `IBOutlet`s `strong` instead of `weak`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // [self.usernameTextbox resignFirstResponder];
    // [self.passwordTextbox resignFirstResponder];
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

---

Comment: Hi i have tried this but it only works for the single textbox as it only hides keyboard of one textbox.

Comment: Hi this worked thats confusing but do not know suddenly started working properly.
Thanks a lot for the help. +1.

Comment: @Tim This method looks at the current view and its subview hierarchy for the text field that is currently the first responder. If it finds one, it asks that text field to resign as first responder.

Comment: do not know how to upvote you answer as it is not allowing unless having 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }
```